# Javascript array keys loop through checking

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, key-value

There is an array that contains key value pairs which the key will contain a manipulative id. The problems is that I intend to achieve a concept of checking the key values which is if the key is exist in the array, then the value will check; or else it will create a new key value pairs for the new and unique id. I looked for the *Object.keys()* function and i find out it will only return array of keys. I tend to check the keys one by one in a for loop tho.

*sorry if I did not explain my question well*

code:

```
var marks = new Array();
function totalScore(critId,score){
var compare = Object.keys(marks);
var result = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < marks.length; i++){ //Looping in marks array
    for(var j = 0; j < compare.length; j++){ //Looping in compare array
        if(compare[j] == marks[i]){ //Comparing the key of the arrays
            marks[i] = score; //If matched update the value of the current key
            result ++;
        }
    }
    if(result == 0){ //If there are no result of the comparison
        marks.critId = score; //Add new key value pair to the array
    }   

}
}
```

Comment: And what's the problem with your code? (input, current output, expected output)

Comment: mind explaining a bit more what is the expected result and where the problem is? I'm having a quite hard time trying to figure out your explanation :P

Comment: What is your input to a function ?

Comment: Do you know about `for ... in`?

Comment: @BenWest actually i no idea about it but thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to add a new key/value pairs if it doesn't exist.

It's better to use an object or an ES6 Map for this case.

```js
var marks = {};
function totalScore(critId, score) {
  if(!(critId in marks)) marks[critId] = score;
}

totalScore(1, 5);
totalScore(2, 8);
totalScore(1, 4);

console.log('marks', marks);
```

Comment: Im glad that this code works but I found a problem that when i use the alert i can't view the keys inside the array instead like in console.log

Comment: Alert expects a string. Convert object to string using `JSON.stringify(marks)`.